# Spring-Data-JPA - Query returns null - EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class with an embedded Id. When I try to search using Jpa Repository, it returns nothing but a null Object. It Looks like the problem is in the Embedded Id, sice I made a test with a class without this and it worked fine.

The query outputed by JPA in the console works fine when I test it agaisnt the database.

And no errors are outputed.

EDIT: There is data in the database

EDIT2: Added equals and hashcode.

EDIT3: The findAll method works.

Entity

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name="C_INFO_CADASTRO")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClienteId id;

    @Column(name="DAT_NASC")
    private DateTime dataNascimento;

    @Column(name="TXT_EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="NOM_CLIENTE")
    private String nomeCliente;

    @Column(name="NUM_CPF")
    private Long numeroCpf;

    public ClienteId getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(ClienteId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public DateTime getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }
    public void setDataNascimento(DateTime dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getNomeCliente() {
        return nomeCliente;
    }
    public void setNomeCliente(String nomeCliente) {
        this.nomeCliente = nomeCliente;
    }
    public Long getNumeroCpf() {
        return numeroCpf;
    }
    public void setNumeroCpf(Long numeroCpf) {
        this.numeroCpf = numeroCpf;
    }

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((numeroCpf == null) ? 0 : numeroCpf.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (numeroCpf == null) {
            if (other.numeroCpf != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!numeroCpf.equals(other.numeroCpf))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

EmbeddedId

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class ClienteId implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="COD_EMP")
    private Long codigoEmpresa;

    @Column(name="COD_FIL")
    private Long codigoFilial;

    @Column(name="NUM_CLI")
    private Long numeroCliente;


    public Long getCodigoEmpresa() {
        return codigoEmpresa;
    }

    public void setCodigoEmpresa(Long codigoEmpresa) {
        this.codigoEmpresa = codigoEmpresa;
    }

    public Long getCodigoFilial() {
        return codigoFilial;
    }

    public void setCodigoFilial(Long codigoFilial) {
        this.codigoFilial = codigoFilial;
    }

    public Long getNumeroCliente() {
        return numeroCliente;
    }

    public void setNumeroCliente(Long numeroCliente) {
        this.numeroCliente = numeroCliente;
    }

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigoEmpresa == null) ? 0 : codigoEmpresa.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((codigoFilial == null) ? 0 : codigoFilial.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((numeroCliente == null) ? 0 : numeroCliente.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ClienteId other = (ClienteId) obj;
        if (codigoEmpresa == null) {
            if (other.codigoEmpresa != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigoEmpresa.equals(other.codigoEmpresa))
            return false;
        if (codigoFilial == null) {
            if (other.codigoFilial != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigoFilial.equals(other.codigoFilial))
            return false;
        if (numeroCliente == null) {
            if (other.numeroCliente != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!numeroCliente.equals(other.numeroCliente))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;


    @Api
    @Component
    public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, ClienteId> {

        Cliente findByNumeroCpf(@Param("numeroCpf") Long numeroCpf);

        Cliente findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);  
    }
```

Service

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
@Path("/cliente")
@Transactional
public class ClienteService {

    @Inject
    private ClienteRepository repository;

    @Inject
    private CodMarcaRepository marcaRepository;

    @GET
    @Path("/cpf/{numeroCpf}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Response findByCpf(@PathParam("numeroCpf") Long numeroCpf){
        Cliente cliente = repository.findByNumeroCpf(numeroCpf);

        if(cliente != null){
            return Response.ok().entity(cliente).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(404).entity(new Cliente()).build();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/email/{email}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response findByEmail(@PathParam("email") String email){
        Cliente cliente = repository.findByEmail(email);

        if(cliente != null){
            return Response.ok().entity(cliente).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(404).entity(new Cliente()).build();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have two methods in my service, one to find by cpf and one to find by email both did not work. I also tried to create a method to find by the composed primary key and it also did not work.

Any help will be apreciated, since I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Are there any records in your database?

Comment: Yes, there is a thousand records in the database.

Comment: Please include the dependency `CodMarcaRepository` or if it is not needed remove it from the code in your question.

Comment: Why do you mark your `ClienteRepository`with `@Api`? This annotation is intended for web-controllers, not for data repository / service layer.

Comment: Can you look for executed SQL query in Hibernate logs and post it here? What is your [RDMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)? The source of problem is not clear from your question. But at least we can help you with debugging.

Comment: I'd start with email: Inspect the value to make sure there is no trailing whitespace in the input value or the database, capitalization is the same any non-ASCII characters are encoded in the same way.

Comment: Why don't you use the new `java.time` classes in place of Joda?

Comment: I'm having the same issue if I execute generated from hibernate SQL in console 6 rows are returned with data.. But appears that spring-data cannot call Entities setters and return ArrayList[null, null, .. 6 times]

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is the source of the problem you are experiencing but you did not override `equals()`/`hashCode()` of the `Embeddable` class. This is mandatory if you want to use that class as an `@EmbeddedId`.

Comment: Right, thank you for reply. Now that you say, I did implement the equals and hashcode, but it did not work. If you have any other suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: If you implemented it, then please update the coding in your question.

Comment: I just did it. Thank's

Comment: I think then you will have to access `numeroCpf` through the id. So in your interface class it will become `Cliente findByIdNumeroCpf(@Param("numeroCpf") Long numeroCpf);` (Notice the extra **Id**)